# Indexing Encrypted Blobs on Azure storage

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-blob-storage

I read the document on [Indexing Documents in Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage). 
My question is if I use encryption [using Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault), can I still using indexing service for searching through the content of my blobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. However, there is an option in **Azure Storage** to index encrypted blobs where the keys are managed by **Microsoft**. See this: [Azure Storage Service Encryption for Data at Rest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-service-encryption)

You can also use **Encryption extensions**: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/partnercatalystteam/2015/06/17/storing-data-securely-in-azure-blob-storage-with-azure-encryption-extensions/

Comment: Have you tried indexing encrypted blobs via Azure Search Service? The 1st link you mentioned talks only about encryption. It does not talk about indexing via Azure Search Service at all.

Comment: I have suggested few folks. This was also one of the asks on the feedback site. This was added couple of months ago. See this: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/10551024-support-for-indexing-encrypted-blobs

Comment: thanks @KaushalKumarPanday! I didn't know about this change indeed.